# Windows 10 Mirroring: "All disks holding extents for a given volume must have the same sector size, and the sector size must be valid."

Tags: windows-10, mirroring

So, here's the scenario: I have two Crucial M500 480GB SSD drives. These are both mirrored using Windows 10's disk mirroring feature, found in the Disk Management area. Both these drives are around 10 years old at this point, so I'm trying to migrate over to newer Crucial MX500 1TB SSD drives.

I proceeded by physically disconnecting one of the M500 drives and in its place, plugged in a MX500 drive. I then turned on the computer and went into Disk Management. I removed the mirror from the remaining M500 drive since its counterpart is now gone. With the mirroring removed, I attempted to re-enable mirroring and selected the MX500 as the new one to mirror onto. And of course, I get this error:

`All disks holding extents for a given volume must have the same sector size, and the sector size must be valid.`

I cannot stress enough: this has to be a Windows 10 bug. I will post an answer to my own question with a summary of how I resolved this and how I am certain this is a bug. This question is less of a question but more reference for all the folks out there who have run into this problem.

Comment: Please avoid putting "Resolution" or similar language in your title. It is enough to just accept the answer.

Comment: What makes you believe it's a bug? The old drive is 512B sectors, the new 4k. That's *exactly* what the error says?

Answer (score 4):

M500 disks have a 512 byte sector size. Source: https://www.storagereview.com/review/crucial-m500-ssd-review

MX500 disks have a 4096 byte sector size. Source: [https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/tech/SSDsAnd4KSectorsII](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/%7Ecks/space/blog/tech/SSDsAnd4KSectorsII)

No you can't mirror across those. The Windows error message is correct. The problem is the mirror repair tool on power loss can't deal with torn writes within a sector, and as a programmer I can't think of how to write that code. So it's wiser to just disallow it.

Answer (score 1):

After a few hours of searching around online and finding no resolutions, I gave up and decided that I'll just restore the mirroring on the M500 drives and use the pair of MX500 drives as extra storage. So, I plugged in all 4 drives and turned on the computer.

I'm back in Windows and, instead of immediately setting up the mirroring on the existing M500 to the M500 I put back in, I decided to try mirroring the existing M500 to one of the MX500. And it worked. Windows 10 automatically created a new partition on the MX500 to match the size of the M500 drive, so about half of it remains unallocated. The new partition is created shows that it is resynching, which is what I expect to see when Windows 10 is synching a pair of drives.

Once the resynching is done, I'll attempt to expand the partition to use the full drive, then attempt to mirror the MX500 that now contains the OS onto the empty MX500 and hopefully that goes smoothly, but the point is the error message had nothing to do with sector sizes, since I changed nothing about the disks to get things to work.